# AttributeError: 'Triangle' object has no attribute 'number_of_sides'

Tags: python

here is my homework assignment:

> Create a class, Triangle. Its init() method should take self, angle1,
> angle2, and angle3 as arguments. Make sure to set these appropriately
> in the body of the init()method.
>
> Create a variable named number_of_sides and set it equal to 3.
>
> Create a method named check_angles. The sum of a triangle's three
> angles is It should return True if the sum of self.angle1,
> self.angle2, and self.angle3 is equal 180, and False otherwise.
>
> Create a variable named my_triangle and set it equal to a new instance
> of your Triangle class. Pass it three angles that sum to 180 (e.g. 90,
> 30, 60).
>
> Print out my_triangle.number_of_sides and print out
> my_triangle.check_angles().

And this is my code:

```
class Triangle:

  def __init__(self, angle1, angle2, angle3):
    number_of_sides = 3

  def check_angles(self):
    if self.angle1 + self.angle2 + self.angle3 == 180:
      return True
    else: 
      return False

my_triangle = Triangle(90, 30, 60)

print(my_triangle.number_of_sides)
print(my_triangle.check_angles)
```

I don't know if I did it correctly, and it shows me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(my_triangle.number_of_sides)
AttributeError: 'Triangle' object has no attribute 'number_of_sides'
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to bind the attribute `number_of_sides` with `self` so you can access it as a class attribute and forgot to set the angle in the `__init__` method.

```
class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, angle1, angle2, angle3):
        # setting angles in __init__ body
        self.angle1 = angle1
        self.angle2 = angle2
        self.angle3 = angle3
        
        # creating variable number_of_sides and setting it to 3
        self.number_of_sides = 3
        
    # method to check if sum of angle is equal to 180 or not.    
    def check_angles(self):
        return self.angle1 + self.angle2 + self.angle3 == 180
    
# creating varible my_triangle        
my_triangle = Triangle(90, 30,60)

#  Print out my_triangle.number_of_sides and print out my_triangle.check_angles().
print(my_triangle.number_of_sides)  # output 3
print(my_triangle.check_angles())  # output True
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't declaring `number_of_sides` as a property of the class. Use `self.number_of_sides = 3` instead.

Inside your `__init__` you must also declare the sides as properties of the class.

So it should look like this:

```py
def __init__(self, number_of_sides, side1, side2, side3):
    self.number_of_sides = 3
    self.side1 = side1
    self.side2 = side2
    self.side3 = side3
```

Comment: It shows me this now:

"3
<bound method Triangle.check_angles of <__main__.Triangle object at 0x7fd4ff4ac4c0>>"

Comment: `check_angles` is a function, you need to invoke it with `check_angles()`

Comment: @anon_misid Have you covered exceptions in your course yet? You could add at the end of `__init__` the following: `if not self.check_angles(): raise ValueError("angles do not sum to 180")` which would prevent you from ever creating a `Triangle` object with angles that add up to the wrong thing.

Comment: You should not be accepting `number_of_sides` as an argument to `__init__`. The value is always `3`; accepting some other value and ignoring it is silly.

Answer (score 0):

`number_of_sides` should logically be a *class* attribute, not an instance attribute. So move the definition outside of `__init__`:

```
class Triangle:
  number_of_sides = 3  # Outside any method, this defines a class attribute
  def __init__(self, angle1, angle2, angle3):
      self.angle1 = angle1
      # ... initialize rest of angles ...
```

Being a class attribute means it consumes no memory on each instance, it's accessible from the class itself, while remaining accessible on the instances (reading `self.number_of_sides` will work just fine, even though it's not defined on a per-instance basis). Since `Triangle`s definitionally have three sides, having it as an instance attribute (implying it might differ from triangle to triangle) is silly.

If you *must* define it on the instance, just assign as `self.number_of_sides = 3` in `__init__`; when you don't qualify the name with `self` inside a method, it's just a local variable that expires when the method finishes running, leaving no trace it was ever defined.

Side-note: Anytime you find yourself with an `if`/`else` that just returns `True` or `False` in each branch, return the test condition itself and save some code (and improve performance a titch), e.g.:

```
  def check_angles(self):
    return self.angle1 + self.angle2 + self.angle3 == 180
```